# Ссылка скачивания вместо воспроизведения

Tags: html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать, что при нажатии на ссылку скачивания MP3 файла, открывалось окно загрузки, а не открывалось воспроизведение mp3 файла... Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 4):

Зря минусуете, вопрос для новичка сложный. Хотя в гугле я думаю решений много.

1. если файл отдаётся через apache/nginx etc, то нужно прописать дополнительные заголовки, аля `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.mp3`.
2. если файл отдаётся программно (через perl, php, C# ...), то нужно просто отдать эти заголовки.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно прописать отдачу файла пользователю в браузер.